# Azure release pipeline not picking up variable from nestedStack.yml file

Tags: java, azure, api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm configuring our Release pipeline so that Integration Tests are automatically run after pull requests are merged to master and deployed to Dev environment.

I'm currently getting a connection error, specifically **java.net.UnknownHostException:** and it looks like my one of my output variables from my nestedStack.yml code is not being imported/read properly:

my-repo/cloud-formation/nestedStack.yml
[image]

You can see there is a property there "ApiGatewayInvokeUrl" which is marked as an Output. It is used on Azure DevOps for the "Integration Testing" task in my "Deploy to Dev" stage. It is written as $(ApiGatewayInvokeUrl) as that's how variables on Azure DevOps are used.

[image]

This Deploy to Dev will "succeed", however when I further inspect the Integration Tests, I see none actually ran and there was a connection error immediately. I can see it is outputting the variable as $(ApiGatewayInvokeUrl) , so it looks like it just reads it as a String, and never substitutes it for the correct URL value:
[image]

I was going off the way another team set up there Integration Tests on a similar pipeline but I might have missed something. Do I need to define $(ApiGatewayInvokeUrl) somewhere in my codebase, or somewhere on Azure? Or am I missing something? I checked the other teams code and didn't see them define it anywhere else, that's why I am ultra confused.

**Update:** I went into AWS API Gateway and copied the invoke URL and hard-coded that into the Azure DevOps Maven (integration testing) goal path and now it's connecting. So it's 100% just not importing that variable for somer reason.

Comment: I agree with 4c74356b41's answer. Yes, in VSTS, **$(variable)** can only be applied when this variable is the one which be defined as a environment variable. You need convert or analyze your nestedStack.yml into variables. Then $() could be available.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define\create the variable to use it (unless its an automatic variable, and this one is definitely not an automatic variable). that variable isnt getting substituted because it doesnt exist (afaik).

Comment: and I have to add this variable on Azure DevOps? I was imitating a working repo from another team and I was searching the DevOps variables they created and I never saw a "ApiGatewayInvokeUrl" so that's why I thought they never defined it so I wouldn't need too..... unless its defined somewhere else in Azure or somewhere else in. the code?

Comment: in Azure DevOps. or in the build itself declares the variable (calculates the variable, perhaps). It cant be defined outside of Azure DevOps (unless build connects to something and pulls the values and creates variables in Azure DevOps).